# How to modify Html.Node in Elm

Tags: elm

How would I go about modifying an existing Html.Node in Elm?

I would like to create a function with the following signature that would add an extra attribute to the input node.

```
  addAttribute : Html msg -> Attribute msg -> Html msg
```

Given

```
  node = Html.div [] [Html.text "dummy"]
  attr = Html.Attributes.style "display" : "inline-block"
```

a call to `addAttribute node attr` should return

```
  Html.div [Html.Attributes.style "display" "inline-block"] [Html.text "dummy"]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Html msg` nodes are opaque by design. There is no way to access their structure and add attributes or children after they have been created.

You will need to find a different approach to building the node.

What I usually do is create some kind of `Cfg msg` record that is passed to some function that generates the node I need. I can then pass styles or optional children through that record.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I was wondering if it was possible to create a function that would allow searching/munging Html nodes (JQuery style - sort of). I will try the approach you suggested.

Comment: jQuery style would require mutation and Elm is an immutable language. In other words, it goes against the core principles of the language. It is better to use some kind of builder pattern where you accumulate the attributes and the children you want in a node.

Comment: Of course it is immutable so it would have to return a new node based on the old node and requested operations. So similar to what you do with `Cfg msg`, except that done directly on `Html.Node`. (But maybe that's impractical - I don't know what Html.Node is under the hood.)

Comment: For the use case in this question I can also try wrapping my nodes in dummy `div`s decorated with `"display" "inline-block"` (as opposed to slapping the attribute directly on the nodes).